# Eevee isn't rendering lighting properly

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

Like the title says: it doesn't render lighting properly.
Here's an example with cycles:

[image]

And here it is (exactly the same settings nothing changed) with eevee:

[image]

Here are my pc specs (although it's not great, it passes the minimum requirements:

> Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 @2.24GHZ
>
> 3gb of RAM
>
> Nvidia Geforce 9600M GT
>
> Windows 10 64-bit

And I checked with Opengl extensions: it does support opengl 3.3

Comment: Can you please show light type and material?

Comment: I left it on default, this is the default cube you get when you start up blender 2.8, so i don't remember what the material is. But the light is a **point** light @Kiskit